# Sharing the static global variable between two files

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker

I have one def.cc file which is build into static library libdefine.a:

def.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
 
 void testFunction();
 typedef struct _epoll_ctxt {
     int epfd;
     int last; 
 } epoll_ctxt;
```

def.cc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "def.h"

static int count = 0;
static epoll_ctxt g_epctxt;

 void testFunction() {
     g_epctxt.epfd = 5;
     printf("The epfd value is %d and val from  .h file", g_epctxt.epfd);
 }
```

I have created the library libdefine.a using def.o
I want to use the variable **g_epctxt** in test.cc (driver function), so I am writting the code as

test.cc:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "def.h"

 extern epoll_ctxt g_epctxt;
 int main() {
     testFunction();
     g_epctxt.epfd = 8;
     printf("The epfd value is %d", g_epctxt.epfd);
     return 0;
 }
```

Compiling using the command: gcc test.cc -L. -ldefine
and getting below error:

```
/tmp/ccdr4Xi5.o: In function `main':
test.cc:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `g_epctxt'
test.cc:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `g_epctxt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone help me here what am I missing.

Comment: Try to Google what `static` in a variable declaration means.

Comment: @MikeCAT, I have already a big code base so I have simplified the problem and put in sample format. I wanted to make use of those global variables in another .cc file

Comment: Instead of exposing global variables, why don't you instead encapsulate the required behavior and then expose interfaces?

Comment: A file scope variable marked `static` cannot be accessed by name from any other source file.  A function in the file where it is defined could return a pointer to it (or, in C++, a reference), or you could create a visible global pointer (or reference) to the static variable, but otherwise, it is inaccessible from outside the source file.

Comment: Why marked both C and C++? They are two different languages

Comment: "static but global" is like saying "cat but dog" or "red but green". The very purpose of using `static` is to block the variable from getting globally exposed. And so the actual problem is your program design. Use setter/getter functions instead.

Comment: This is clearly C++. Your files are named `.cc`. Please tag accordingly.

Comment: @Moia, Yes, these concepts are also same thats why tagged both.

Answer (score 1):

In `def.cc` the following declaration denotes a variable with *internal linkage*:

```
static epoll_ctxt g_epctxt;
```

C++ standard [section 6.6 §3.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#3.1):

> A name having namespace scope has internal linkage if it is the name of
>
> - a variable, variable template, function, or function template that is explicitly declared `static`

Furthermore, in [section 6.6 §2.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#2.3):

> When a name has internal linkage, the entity it denotes can be referred to by names from other scopes in the same translation unit.

Thus, when you declare a `static` global variable in a translation unit (in this case a `def.cc` file), you can only refer to it inside the same translation unit. Names with *internal linkage* are also referred to as *TU-locals* (*translation-unit locals*) by the standard.

Based [section 6.6 §18](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#18.sentence-1) we can point out that your program is ill-formed:

> If a declaration that appears in one translation unit names a TU-local entity declared in another translation unit that is not a header unit, the program is ill-formed.

It looks like you only want to have a single instance of the variable `g_epctxt` in all other translation units. Thus, you would want the variable to have *external linkage*. To do this you only have to define the variable in `def.cc` without the specifier `static`:

```
// def.cc

// Global variables have external linkage by default
epoll_ctxt g_epctxt;
```

Though, it is good practice to also declare this type of variable `extern` in the header file (`def.h`). This way you don't have to redeclare the variable every time you use it, and it also clarifies that the variable is designed be used in other translation units:

```
// def.h
extern epoll_ctxt g_epctxt;
```

With the `extern` declaration above, you should remove the now redundant declaration of `g_epctxt` from `test.cc` (and other *.cc* files):

```
// test.cc

// This is redundant and should be removed
extern epoll_ctxt g_epctxt;
```

You can also think of it this solution like so: If you wanted to change the name or type of the variable `g_epctxt`, would you want to only do it in `def.cc` and `def.h`, or in `def.c` and all the different *.cc* files it has been declared in.